# How to reverse punctuation marks using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, expression, arabic, right-to-left

I need a regular expression in python in a format like this one to reverse the Arabic punctuation marks from the right start of the word to the left end of it like "!, ‏‎؟‎, ., ‏‎،‎," and to reverse "-, ...,".

```
file_content = re.sub(r'^ +', r'', file_content, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Example:

```
؟هل أنت بخير
```

I need it to be:

```
هل أنت بخير؟
```

Comment: Do you want to apply the regex to a sentence or to the whole file?

Comment: To the whole subtitle file in text format.

Comment: So, there is more than one place where the marks should be reversed?

Comment: Yes, all the lines in the subtitle.

Comment: You probably should include this sample in the question with the line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
file_content = re.sub(ur'^(.*)(؟)$', r'$2$1', file_content, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: It does not seems to work, i'm using it with python 2.7.

Comment: I see. For Python 2.7 you would have specify `u` for string literals that contain Unicode characters. I've updated my answer accordingly.